# MVC design. Appropriate Connections

Tags: object-oriented-design, mvc

[image: Class Diagram]

OK... I am attempting to implement a simple MVC windows application...

There is a helper class (ConvertPDF) that is instantiated by the Controller.

As it is currently implemented, the Converter directly updates the View and the Model. I have an inner feeling that this is just bad form! I have included these two associations in the class diagram.

Should the Controller be notified that ConvertPDF has finished? Once the Controller knows this, then it is responsible for updating the View and the DataSet.

If this is the preferred approach, can anyone direct me to some examples. I imagine there will be events and delegates involved.

Thanks.

Comment: Related on SO: [In Model-View-Controller, is it ever okay for the view to depend on the model?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32597330/6369859)

Comment: It's not generally significant. The main thing about what is generally called MVC is partitioning the system in data structures, views and business logic. The rest is best suited for hand waving, educational signaling and bikeshedding.

Answer (score 1):

In general the Controller should update the Model, which is mapped to the View

It looks like you've gone a bit off track, Mixing your Model and Controller into the Album class.

Although this is good OOP for MVC you should add an extra controller class where you put the logic for button presses, events etc. ie

```
ButtonClicked
{
     //trigger non business logic event
     this.ViewModel.ShowProgressBar = true
     this.Album.DoThing();
     this.ViewModel.AlbumData = this.Album.Data
     this.ViewModel.ShowProgressBar = false
}
```

If you keep Business logic methods on your Album object then possibly you could add another  AlbumViewModel class to bind the view to. This can simplify your Business Model Graph if its not a 1-1 match with the view.

Exposing a low level object like a dataset as a Model isn't a great idea, unless you view uses a component which directly consumes it, say a graph or grid. Even then you are probably better off with an object, as you will want extras such as xAxis legend, sortedByCol etc

My advice would be to start afresh with a new AlbumViewModel class. Put everything the view needs on it. Then make a new AlbumController class, add your business models and extra logic there, work out how to create the View Model when the events happen.

Once you have those named objects, you can trim things back and decide where you want the various bits of logic to go. Business Model or Controller.

Never touch the view directly. That should all be done by binding (you dont say what framework you are using?)

Comment: Thanks for your full and prompt response.  I am now even more confused!  The class Album, I hope, is the Controller. How is the function of the Model mixed in here? My poor understanding is that the Controller contains the GUI logic, which then is presented in the View.   What would a  new AlbumViewModel class do?

Comment: Model, which is mapped to the View.....   Does this imply the View is not linked at all to the Controller?    OMG I really have misunderstood MVC

Comment: yes. but obvs there is a link behind the scenes. what framework are you using? c# wpf? asp mvc?

Comment: @Oscar I've occasionally seen misguided articles/blogs advocating logic in a Controller, but that really isn't what a Controller is for; a Controller has one role which is to create and inject the *Model* (a.k.a *ViewModel* a.k.a. *Model-of-the-View* into the View itself).  The important take-away with regards to MVC, MVP and other MV* patterns is they are **GUI** patterns, and therefore don't cover business logic or business models at all.  Controllers may call into a Business Logic Layer to pull data used for creating a ViewModel, but Business Logic itself is not part of MVC.

Comment: hmm you have to be careful when you try to say what MVC *is*. Originally the controller referred to the mouse or keyboard and the in the first asp mvc entity framework was the M, razor was the V so yeah your controller had all the logic. With a windows app now though MVVM seems to be all the rage

Comment: @Ewan I don't think that's accurate; the concept possibly even predates the name (it has been around for decades, long before ASP.NET or C#), but it has always been a purely UI pattern.   It evolved because Graphical platforms became more advanced.   In the beginning, early GUI libraries needed to separate elements responsible for layout/appearance away from event systems. Controllers used to be *Windowing message brokers* which would forward data to/from a View; that stuff is handled by an O/S or framework nowadays, so modern Controllers are more like a thin layer of data-forwarding "glue".

Comment: @Ben that is more to my understanding. Where does the business logic go? In this app, the only manipulation apart from displaying/navigating the GUI is in the Converter.

Comment: @Ewan .. "a link behind the scenes" what would that be? I have developed the app with C#. I did not know that would be referred to as a framework. I thought that MVC was a pattern/framework. I am attempting to reverse engineer my application so that it follow this.

Comment: @Oscar ben is not wrong, but MVC isn't just one well defined thing. It depends (in your case) what project type you are using. If you have an old fashioned winforms app with the form designer your View is coupled to your controller (code behind) its not really MVC. If you are doing a WPF app you can bind your XAML view to a model and write controllers. But in that case you would be better to use the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @Ewan .... aha, some light! I am using a plane old Win Forms approach. So does this mean I am beating my head against a wall?

Comment: if you google 'winforms mvc' you can see some examples of how people have tried to do it, but essentially you are inventing an implementation as you go. If its a new app use WPF

Answer (score 0):

the converterPDF class should return the result of it's calculation to the controller and the controller updates the model. the view should be observing the model for changes (Observer design pattern) and get updated when the model changes.

Comment: So the view directly observes the model?  So must be a connection between the two. I have been under the impression that the Contoller must act as an intermediary between the Model and the View.

Comment: first of all there isn't a single MVC as it adaptes with the environment, in web environment for exemple it's very hard to make the view on the client side observe the model on the server side so in this environment the view doesn't observe the model directly, but in desktops applications it is possible and easy. use the observer design pattern where the model will be the observable and the view is the observer